# excel formula for two different columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

`Colors Name    Comments
Red    Chris    I don’t like Red and my name is paul
Green   Max     I am Red and I like green 
Yellow  Ed      I am Chris and I love yellow
Pink    John    I am kelly and I love black`

I need a formula written where the output needs to be in column D .  If "Comments" in Column C contains any of the items in Column A and Column B then Comment should be the output . 
For ex: A1 : Red B1: Chris C1 I don’t like Red and my name is paul then output in column D should be :I don’t like Red and my name is paul

Comment: Can you please format the question properly so that it becomes more clear what you're asking? (and remove the non-existing image at the top?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in column D (specifically cell D1), then drag it down

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,C1))),C1,"")
```

This will work even if the capitalization is different between the search term and the comments cell. One potential problem is that if your color or name are part of another word, it will give a false match, like if your color is red and the word "scared" is in the comments cell. Hope this helps.

P.S. When you're asking a question, look lower on the page and you'll see what the formatting will look like. It was a bit difficult sorting through your weird formatting.

Comment: I need the answer in column D to search all items in column A and B and then check if it is present in C , return me output of entire C string if any of it matches.

Comment: @Craxy That's what this does. Set up your worksheet like your example says with columns A, B, and C holding the color, name, and comments strings. Then paste my formula in column D1. You can copy that formula down the column. The formula searches cell C1 for the contents of A1 and B1, and if either of them is present in C1, D1 will print the contents of C1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this which should go into cell D1:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(A1),UPPER(C1))),ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(B1),UPPER(C1)))), "", C1)
```